# No resource identifier found for attribute adSize in package

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to add AdMob ads in my application.

In the manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

In the xml activity's layout I use:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My java code in the main activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I receive this error

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package

Answer (score 1):

Other people who has faced this issue had solution by replacing `/res` with `/lib` in custom layout nampespace.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" will be

xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.yourApppackage.yourClass"
```