# Package error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner in android currently am using android studio IDE. While compiling the project I see:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package.
```

this project was developed in eclipse and uploaded in play store before 6 months but while compiling it in android studio am getting the above error message.

I have no solutions for this. Can any of you give me a possible solution?

Comment: Are you trying to use Admob? Could you post your activity layout with adSize attribute? Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29999674/2091181 ?

Comment: yes am trying Admob..i visited your link while i tried that again getting errors

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package

Comment: In your build.gradle file try changing your service with this ** compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0' **

Answer (score 0):

Change your Layout

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" will be

xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.yourAppPackege.yourClass"
```

Note->/res in path is replaced with /lib

Comment: i replaced what you have said..still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can change in your xml layout with this

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Or Like this

```
< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    />
```

It might me help you out.
Thank you

Comment: please post your xml here.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Comment: still getting the same error :-( No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned in your Question its look you have any gradle related problem.
So now,If you have built your project in different IDE like Eclipse then you should open this project with."**Import Project with(Eclipse ADT,Gradle,etc.)**".This thing will convert your other IDE project in Android Studio Project.
If you have done this then you can **Rebuild Project** from Build option.

Comment: yeah what you have said is correct but am having error in packages once solving those errors i can import it to android studio until clearing the errors i can't import the project

Comment: If you have non android studio project then,When you first time import your project to android studio you must open this project with option "Import Project with(Eclipse ADT,Gradle,etc.)'.

Comment: am running it in eclipse IDE

Comment: Ohk but your question shows you get this error when you compile your project in android studio.

Comment: if i have error means i can't import it in studio write..tats y am trying to solve those errors in eclipse after solving i will import it too studio